# UPDATE: why is user role not changing after edit in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, node-modules, nodejs-server

i am trying to make a authentication user part by nodejs/expressjs with mongodb where users will have different roles and the parameters of the users will be saved in mongodb. in case of signing in for every user, they will be saved as "user" by default. after edit, its role will change into admin or moderator and this role change will be updated in mongodb also.

here is my userschema in node.js/Express.js:

```
 const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 8,
  },
  displayName: {
    
    type: String,
  },
  role: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['user', 'moderator', 'admin'],
    default: 'user',
  },
  resetLink: {
    data: String,
    default: "",
  },
});

module.exports=User=mongoose.model("user",userSchema)
```

here is router.put for editing and updating the role:

```
    router.put("/:username/newrole",async(req,res)=>{
  
let role,username;

try {
  username = req.params.username;
  
   console.log(username);

  
  
const result = await User.updateOne(
  { username: req.body.username },
  { $set: { role: req.body.role } }
);  

  console.log("result = ", result);

  res.status(200).json({ msg: "User role has been updated successfully!" });
} catch(e) {
  if (User == null) {
    console.log(e)
    res.status(400).json({ msg: "no such username found!" });
  } else {
    User: User, 
    console.log(e);
    res.status(405).json({ msg: "Error updating!" });
  }
}
 
})
```

i am using the postman to check the code. the url for the edit is http://localhost:5000/users/admin/newrole where admin is the username of the user which role is going to be changed. and in the body row of the post i am giving the input as below:

```
{
"role":"user"
}
```

but output is showing successfuly user role changed but the console.log(result):

```
result =  {
  n: 0,
  nModified: 0,
  opTime: {
    ts: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 2, high_: 1611010685 },
    t: 7
  },
  electionId: 7fffffff0000000000000007,
  ok: 1,
  '$clusterTime': {
    clusterTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 2, high_: 1611010685 },
    signature: { hash: [Binary], keyId: [Long] }
  },
  operationTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 2, high_: 1611010685 }
}
```

and here is a snapshot of [image: of my db where user role is not changing]

**the databse user role is showing role: null which is suppose to be changing into "user". where did i make the mistake?**

please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally solved it. here is the following code for update the role:

```
router.patch('/:id/update',async(req,res)=>{
 
try {
 const user=await User.updateOne({_id:req.params.id},{$set:{role:req.body.role}},{
    new:true
  })
  console.log(req.body.role); 
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e)
}
})
```

in postman i had to use x-www-form-urlencoded where i have selected key as role and value is admin or user or whatever i want acording to enum. and the request url must contain the _id number as i have filtered by it and it would be a patch request.

that has done the trick.

but thanx J.F. for help. your chat helped me to understand about mongoose and mongodb commands and nodejs/expressjs handling the route.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `user.updateOne({role: req.body.role});` the response is not the user updated but something like `{ ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 }`.

So next line where yo do `user.save();` is not the expected behaviour.

Instead of use three DB calls you can do it into only one:

```
await user.findOneAndUpdate({ username: username },{$set:{role: req.body.role}})
```

What you are doing here is: For the document where `username` is equal to -your username loaded from `req.body.username`- then set the value `role` as value into `req.body.role`.

Comment: the output is still showing the same: {
    "msg": "no such username found!"
} i am adding a snapshot of my database so that it can be understod how users are saved

Comment: The no exists an user with that username

Comment: but before the line of that res.status(400) error message console.log(username) is showing undefined and console.log(role) is showing undefined also

Comment: try {
  username = req.body.username;
  //await user.save();
  await user.findOneAndUpdate(
    { username: username },
    { $set: { role: req.body.role } }
  );
  console.log(role)
   //user.save();
  console.log(role);
  res.status(200).json({ msg: "User role has been updated successfully!" });
} : this is the code after ur suggetion.seems like in try/catch, try is unable to find the username that i am giving. i searched for the slug in nodejs, it is written that there would be no need to use that. so the redirect of username is a good idea or shoud i look for the user _id?

Comment: Catch the exception and do `console.log(e)` to see what is the error.

Comment: The server has started on port: 5000
MongoDB connected TypeError: Cannot read property 'findOneAndUpdate' of undefined
    at C:\Myfiles\Reactjs\Projects\test-projects\routes\userRouter.js:275:14

Comment: Have you imported `user` from your schema class? `var user = require(./path/to/your/userModel')`

Comment: ofcourse. the same file is executing the register email activation login password reset thing. here are past of the imported ones: const router = require("express").Router();
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const auth = require("../middleware/auth");
const User=require("../models/userModel")
const _=require('lodash')

Comment: Is not the same `User` and `user`. You have declared `let user` too. Query is with `User.findOneAndUpdate(...)`.

Comment: it's a good point and hat's why i turned every "user" into "User" and found the warning as following: DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: `findOneAndUpdate()` and `findOneAndDelete()` without the `useFindAndModify` option set to false are deprecated. See: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html#findandmodify
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created). now the mongodb is showing role: null.. we are going the in right direction i think

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227506/discussion-between-j-f-and-ali).